# Remove gradients from standard applications

Tags: unity, themes

I currently try to make my own theme with the Ambiance theme as template. I want to make a flat theme, so I currently try to replace the gradients with `background-color: ...`. However, I am not able to identify where these gradients are defined:

[image]

**1.**: There is a quite subtile gradient on the header in most of the default applications like `gedit`, `nautilus`, the settings app, and even `unity-tweak-tool` (Below the `UnityDecoration .top`).

**2.**: There is a gradient like the background of the `Home` location.

My main problem is that I don't know how these elements are named, so I could quickly search for the class name or so. I failed to find a proper documentation for this.

I tried to look at other designs, but they where all for gtk-3.0, not gtk-3.2 which is used by Ubuntu 16.10 (most of them don't work). However, even if I would have found a design, it's way too much source code to find it without having the proper names...

So my questions are:

**How can these particular gradients be removed?**

**Is there *some kind of* documentation for the class names and the corresponding UI elements?**

Answer (score 0):

After hours of try-and-error I finally got it.

**1.**: The selector `.primary-toolbar, headerbar, .maximized headerbar.titlebar:not(:backdrop)` (I don't know which one of them exactly) in `gtk-widgets.css`

**2.**: The selector is `placessidebar.sidebar row:selected` in `gtk-widgets.css`

I did *not* find a documentation anyway...